# Ignore Exception in Observable and Continue

Tags: c#, udp, system.reactive

Consider this Observable:

```
_listener = Observable.Defer(() => _deviceTypeProvider.GetDeviceTypes().ToObservable()
            .SelectMany(CreateUdpListener, CreateMessage)
            .OfType<DeviceMessage>()
            .SelectMany(InjectTestMode)
            .OfType<DeviceMessage>()
            .Do(async message => await PublishMessage(message)))
            .Retry()
            .Subscribe(OnMessageReceive, OnError, OnComplete);
```

This works fine except when there is an exception thrown in either `CreateMessage` or `InjectTestMode`.

I'd like the Observable to skip the item in the sequence which generated the exception and carry on.

I've read about Catch but the example I found allow you to start a new Observable and I would like to carry on with the one I have.
At the moment the entire sequence restarts which includes the UDP ports which I'd like to avoid if possible.

**[Update]**

A colleague and I re-read some of the comments about using `IEnumerable<IObservable<>>` or `IObservable<IObservable<>>` and came up with this which works! But is it right/best practice?

In the event of an exception in the inner observable I'm wondering if it will only drop the packets from the `ReceiveAsync` event that was in flight.

```
var listeners = Observable.Defer(() => _deviceTypeProvider.GetDeviceTypes()
                .ToObservable()
                .Select(UdpListener)
                .SelectMany(listener =>
                {
                  return Observable.Defer(() => Observable
                    .FromAsync(listener.UdpClient.ReceiveAsync)
                    .Where(x => x.Buffer.Length > 0)
                    .Repeat()
                    .Select(result => CreateMessage(listener.DeviceType, result))
                    .SelectMany(InjectTestMode)
                    .OfType<DeviceMessage>()
                    .Do(async message => await PublishMessage(message)))
                    .Retry();
                })).Retry();

_listener = listeners.Subscribe(OnMessageReceive, OnError, OnComplete);
```

Comment: I would avoid that sneaky `Do` method. It looks like that logic belongs in your `OnMessageReceive` method

Comment: I total agree, but I saw that I should never have an async method call in my subscription because of async void. It feels wrong that in fact the only thing left in the subscription in a logging message!

Comment: I see your reasoning, so what you would do instead is create a continuation. Something like `.SelectMany(message=>PublishMessage(message).ToObservable())`. and yes, it is normally a code smell if your OnNext handler in your subscribe does nothing. Rx is about consuming asynchronous/observable sequences, so you should be observing them! ;-)

Comment: Gotcha, yes excellent!

Comment: As Publish on returns a Task I see the subscription puts out a Unit, is this still ok ?

Comment: Yeah, should be fine. `Unit` is the functional equivalent of `void` in a synchronous world or `Task` in _normal_ .NET asynchronous world. We use it alot to signify that the sequence produced a value, but the value is unimportant. If my memory serves me correctly other languages like Scala only have the `Task<T>` equivalent (Future) so you are required to use future[Unit] instead of the missing `Task` type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for `IObservable<T>` specifies that a sequence must match this grammar:

```
OnNext* (OnCompleted|OnError)
```

There cannot be any more values emitted after an exception or completion. If you manually make an observable that violates this grammar, you can expect undefined behavior when you use any of the existing Rx operators. Not good!

Model your query as an `IEnumerable<IObservable<T>>` or `IObservable<IObservable<T>>` if you want to get retry behavior, where the outer `IEnumerable<*>` or `IObservable<*>` never throws.

Comment: Thanks I'll go and some research, any chance of giving me simple code snippet to illustrate the concept ?

Comment: I could not find any examples of this concept but I'll keep looking. Right now my code opens and closes the UDP ports (as per the retry and defer) which is not great but better than we had before.

Comment: @JohnKattenhorn If you have a cold observable (meaning it only does anything once you subscribe) but want to make it a hot observable (meaning it produces values regardless of whether there are subscribers) then you can do that by using the `Publish` method. That will give you an `IConnectableObservable<T>` on which you can call `Connect`. It sounds like that is what you want at this point.

Comment: Yep I've got a cold observable right now and that seemed fine for our needs. Does moving to a hot observable give me more flexibility in terms of ignoring exceptions ? Given we have been working on this piece of code on and off for several months and it's getting better but still got problems I'd hate to have to try to refactor into a hot observable unless there was a compelling reason to do so.

Comment: Maybe starting here http://reactivex.io/intro.html, or here IntroToRx.com* and spending around 4-8hrs reading will save 10x that in making basic mistakes (like misunderstanding the protocol). *disclosure, I am the author.

Comment: Hi Lee, Yep, it's great site - full credit to you. I'm finding hard to jump from the examples to the situation I have, I'll keep reading.

Answer (score 0):

Make some static extension function, pass delegate to it, and wrap it up into try{}catch{} inside this function.